# Trouble with IDs and for loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var week = 5;
  var players = 8;
  var numbers = [];
  var array = [];
  for (o = 0; o < players; o++) {
    for (i = 0; i < week + 1; i++) {
      var improved = i + 1;
      var oString = o.toString();
      var iString = i.toString();
      var id = "#" + oString + iString;
      var rawText = $(id).text();
      var refined = Number(rawText);
      array.push(refined);
    }
    numbers.push(array);
    array = [];
  }
  for (p = 0; i < numbers.length; p++) {
    var total1 = 0;
    $.each(numbers[0], function() {
      total1 += this;
    });
  }
  $("#total1").text(total1);
  for (p = 0; i < numbers.length; p++) {
    var total2 = 0;
    $.each(numbers[0], function() {
      total2 += this;
    });
  }
  $("#total2").text(total2);
  for (p = 0; i < numbers.length; p++) {
    var total3 = 0;
    $.each(numbers[0], function() {
      total3 += this;
    });
  }
  $("#total3").text(total3);
  for (p = 0; i < numbers.length; p++) {
    var total4 = 0;
    $.each(numbers[0], function() {
      total4 += this;
    });
  }
  $("#total4").text(total4);
  for (p = 0; i < numbers.length; p++) {
    var total5 = 0;
    $.each(numbers[0], function() {
      total5 += this;
    });
  }
  $("#total5").text(total5);
  var total = total1 + total2 + total3 + total4 + total5;
  $("#total").text(total);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Week 7</th>
      <th>Week 8</th>
      <th>Week 9</th>
      <th>Week 10</th>
      <th>Week 11</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Matt Ryan</td>
      <td>QB</td>
      <td id="01">11</td>
      <td id="02">15</td>
      <td id="03">00</td>
      <td id="04">14</td>
      <td id="05">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Marshawn Lynch</td>
      <td>RB</td>
      <td id="11">06</td>
      <td id="12">01</td>
      <td id="13">09</td>
      <td id="14">40</td>
      <td id="15">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Calvin Johsnon</td>
      <td>WR</td>
      <td id="21">00</td>
      <td id="22">00</td>
      <td id="23">00</td>
      <td id="24">00</td>
      <td id="25">00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Allen Hurns</td>
      <td>WR</td>
      <td id="31">00</td>
      <td id="32">04</td>
      <td id="33">23</td>
      <td id="34">17</td>
      <td id="35">05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A.J. Green</td>
      <td>WR</td>
      <td id="41">00</td>
      <td id="42">00</td>
      <td id="43">10</td>
      <td id="44">02</td>
      <td id="45">18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Julius Thomas</td>
      <td>Tight End</td>
      <td id="51">02</td>
      <td id="52">02</td>
      <td id="53">09</td>
      <td id="54">18</td>
      <td id="55">00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Matt Bryant</td>
      <td>Kicker</td>
      <td id="61">00</td>
      <td id="62">03</td>
      <td id="63">00</td>
      <td id="64">15</td>
      <td id="65">15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Texans</td>
      <td>Defense</td>
      <td id="71">04</td>
      <td id="72">07</td>
      <td id="73">12</td>
      <td id="74">00</td>
      <td id="75">08</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="total1">00</td>
      <td id="total2">00</td>
      <td id="total3">00</td>
      <td id="total4">00</td>
      <td id="total5">00</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>Total: <span id="totalAll"></span>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Recently, I was charged with creating a fantasy football website for my group of friends, having minimal Javascript and HTML experience. I don't mind manually inputing data from the NFL website, but I thought it would be cool to have a script to automatically add up the numbers in the table. But, the code I wrote doesn't work. Nobody I know has any knowledge in Computer Science, and Ive turned to Google throughout the whole process. The browser console returns no errors. What I expect to happen is the total points from all of my tds for each week go into the week total at the bottom, and then the week totals be added up into the final total. What really happens is nothing. Half the time, when I change something, the page crashes.

I cant seem to get a JSfiddle to run without crashing on run-time, so im putting it into pastebin
http://pastebin.com/Wb3ENMZY

All the for loops at the end are temporary, to be taken down when the first part works.

Comment: You'd have better luck with a more targeted question that shows some code and offers a specific line of questioning.

Comment: pastebin.com blocked for me

Comment: The issue is I dont really know whats wrong, but suspect its something to do with my variables.

Comment: The pastebin should be set to public

Comment: It's a shame that there are no fantasy sports apps out there already.

Comment: As a general hint upon what I understood from your question: Similar things (entities) you want to get there sum identify them with one class name instead of multiple ids. In this way you will be able to collect them in simple loop.

Comment: I pasted your code in. What is `main.js` and where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure why your code wouldn't work in JSFiddle
Here's a fiddle with a work example of what you were trying to accomplish [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ognr9q7/1/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Week 7</th>
        <th>Week 8</th>
        <th>Week 9</th>
        <th>Week 10</th>
        <th>Week 11</th>
    </tr>
        <thead>
            <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Matt Ryan</td>
        <td>QB</td>
        <td id="01">11</td>
        <td id="02">15</td>
        <td id="03">00</td>
        <td id="04">14</td>
        <td id="05">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Marshawn Lynch</td>
        <td>RB</td>
        <td id="11">06</td>
        <td id="12">01</td>
        <td id="13">09</td>
        <td id="14">40</td>
        <td id="15">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Calvin Johsnon</td>
        <td>WR</td>
        <td id="21">00</td>
        <td id="22">00</td>
        <td id="23">00</td>
        <td id="24">00</td>
        <td id="25">00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Allen Hurns</td>
        <td>WR</td>
        <td id="31">00</td>
        <td id="32">04</td>
        <td id="33">23</td>
        <td id="34">17</td>
        <td id="35">05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A.J. Green</td>
        <td>WR</td>
        <td id="41">00</td>
        <td id="42">00</td>
        <td id="43">10</td>
        <td id="44">02</td>
        <td id="45">18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Julius Thomas</td>
        <td>Tight End</td>
        <td id="51">02</td>
        <td id="52">02</td>
        <td id="53">09</td>
        <td id="54">18</td>
        <td id="55">00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Matt Bryant</td>
        <td>Kicker</td>
        <td id="61">00</td>
        <td id="62">03</td>
        <td id="63">00</td>
        <td id="64">15</td>
        <td id="65">15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Texans</td>
        <td>Defense</td>
        <td id="71">04</td>
        <td id="72">07</td>
        <td id="73">12</td>
        <td id="74">00</td>
        <td id="75">08</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="total1">00</td>
        <td id="total2">00</td>
        <td id="total3">00</td>
        <td id="total4">00</td>
        <td id="total5">00</td>
    </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
<p>Total: <span id="totalAll"></span>
</p>
```

Note the addition of the `<thead>` and the `<tbody>` this is so we can easily select the body rows in JQuery

**Code**

```
//Make a list of values for each column
var sums = [0,0,0,0,0];

//Go through each row in the body of the table
$("tbody tr").each(function () {
    //We start at 2 because thats the firs of the weeks columns
    for(var i = 2; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        //Add the current column's value to the sum. Note we use :eq() selector to get the i'th column
        sums[i-2] += parseInt($("td:eq("+i+")", this).html());
    }
});

var total = 0;

//Go through each column sum totalling it and writing it to the appropriate column
for(var i = 0; i < sums.length; i++)
{
    total += sums[i];
    $("#total" + (i + 1)).html(sums[i]);
}

//Write the total
$("#totalAll").html(total);
```

From your original code

```
for (p = 0; i < numbers.length; p++) {
    var total1 = 0;
    $.each(numbers[0], function() {
      total1 += this;
    });
  }
```

This was causing Javascript to loop forever. Your for loop will loop until `i < numbers.length` but `i` isn't defined here. You probably mean `p` there. After replacing the `i` with `p` it no longer looped forever but each column would have the same value, `numbers[0]` should be changed for each column you're parsing.
I'm still having issues with your original code even after fixing those errors though.